# C++ optimization, using > instead of <=

Tags: c++, optimization

Is it more expensive to check '<=' rather than '>' ?

The first one checks both < and ==, but '>' does just one check.

Or maybe the compiler optimizes this?

Comment: is it your bottleneck?

Comment: It's more like his curiosity and perfectionism, which are rather good to have.

Comment: @DesmondHume: I cannot agree here. If you want to write assembler learn the instructions and know the details, if you want to write in a higher level language, let the compiler/optimizer do it's job. If one of the two expressions was more expensive than the other, the compiler can transform one into the other in the same way that the programer can. The advantage is that the compiler **does know** the cost of the expressions and how much it matters in the context of the generated code. The compiler will usually do a much better job than the average programmer in optimizing the details.

Answer (score 15):

It depends on what you're comparing, but for the build-in types, both are generally just one machine instruction.

Answer (score 4):

There's rarely any noticeable difference. If you're thinking of this kind of optimizations, I bet, you're not optimizing the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

For non built in types you can overload both operators as you wish:

```
class Foo
{
public:    
    bool operator<=(const Foo &other) const
    {

    }

    bool operator<(const Foo &other) const
    {

    }

};
```

So if comparison operators is the bottleneck of your application you are able to optimize your operators and `<=` can be calculated in different manner then calling `<` and `==`

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: the point is that <= can be implemented in another way then calling < and ==

Comment: That's worth elaborating and writing in the answer, I think.

Answer (score 0):

No. both have the same cost. Assuming you are using a known standard compiler not a fancy one

Comment: Compiler shouldn't even matter, they both should have the same cost at the machine level

Answer (score 0):

No. `<=` is essentially the same as `>` with an extra NOT, and `>=` is the same as `<` with a NOT. (Which ones, if any, have an extra NOT I'm not sure but they are essentially all the same at the hardware level.)

Comment: In most processors, the results will be a compare instruction, which sets a number of flags in the condition code, followed by a conditional jump on the condition code.  I'm not aware of any processor which would require an extra not, regardless of the comparison; they all have conditional jump operators corresponding to all six operators.

Comment: This assumes integer types or similar. For floating-point, `a<=b` is not the same as `! (a>b)`. E.g., if `a` is a NaN, the former is false but the latter is true.